# Display begin and end of string (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function for substring:

```
$('#text').on('mouseup', function(e){ 
    var text = "There are a lot of text";
    if (text != '') {
        $('.ppr .sel_text').text(text.trim().substr(0,21) + "..."); 
    }
});
```

How can I get only begining end ending of the text string?

For example, now result is "There are a lot of te...".

I would like to get: "There are ... text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.prototype.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

> Warning: Although String.prototype.substr(…) is not strictly deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards"), it is defined in Annex B of the ECMA-262 standard, whose introduction states:
>
> ---
>
> … All of the language features and behaviours specified in this annex have one or more undesirable characteristics and in the absence of legacy usage would be removed from this specification. …
>   … Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours when writing new ECMAScript code. …

Use [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead. You have to take the string from both start and end. You can try the following way:

```js
$('#text').on('mouseover', function(e){ 
  var text = "There are a lot of text";
  if (text != '') {
    $('.sel_text').text(text.substring(0,10) + "..." + text.trim().substring(text.length - 5));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">There are a lot of text<div>
<div class="sel_text"></div>
```